# PHP service in Google Cloud Run suddenly stops responding to all incoming requests

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-run

I am running a PHP (8.1) backend application in Google Cloud Run. The backend is connected to a MYSQL database running in Google Cloud SQL.
Over the last two weeks, we have had three complete outages. The backend server does not respond to any requests, resulting in our app and website being completely down.

Before this happened the first time, the server has been running for many months without any similar problems. I first suspected that this had something to do with some specs on either the backend or the database, but looking at the graphs, I cannot see any obvious reasons why it should all go down.

Notice how the traffic goes down every night, but is still spiky, before it went completely flat around 4PM today:
[image: Cpu utilization of the database]

I then looked at the stats from our Cloud Run server to find any indication there. We are running with relatively high specs, and a flexible container instance size, so this should not cause any troubles like this. Container memory and CPU utilization drops dead all of a sudden. It seems there are no unusual activity going on before the service decided to die.

[image: Cloud run metrics]

Our Sentry dashboard shows that there are no captured events from the down time period.
However, looking at the logs of the backend service in Google Cloud Logs Explorer, it seems there are heaps of 200 responses in this time interval. By looking at the logs, I don't see any indication that anything is wrong.

The only thing I could think of to resolve this problem, was to redeploy the service inside Google Cloud Run, effectively spinning up a new container with the exact same code and specs. Then it started working again, and has been working since, but I have no idea what have happened.
As far as I can think of, we don't have any code or config related changes that could lead to any kind of problems like this.

Does anyone have any thoughts? The only thing I can think of is some sort of memory leak that suddenly gets out of hand. But I assume that should have been able to trace back in some way. If this was the case, I'm also thinking it should have happened more often over a long period of time. Not running nicely for a long time, then down 3 times in 2 weeks.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error occurs in the browser because the browser is making cross-origin requests and that application is telling the browser to fail those requests. Your problem is not with Cloud Run. Your problem is with the URL that the browser is calling.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't really help me. I need to understand why my "application is telling the browser to fail those requests". What do you mean there is a problem with the URL that the browser is sending? It has worked thousands of times before and after this incident.

Comment: The first step is to figure out what URL is causing the CORS error, Then implement CORS response headers at the server for that URL which allows the browser to call the URL (GET, POST, etc). Your question does not have those details.

Comment: Could you share your requests?

Comment: I think the CORS is not really the problem here, it is just a side effect when the backend is down. Issuing a request directly from Postman also failed reaching the backend.
Is there anyone who has any input on Google Cloud, and if this could be the culprit?

Comment: Why are you making cross origin requests if the backend is **yours**?

Comment: I'm not making cross origin requests. But when the backend fails, it seems like this is the error message that pops up, but it is not really related to the root cause of the problem. Do you have any idea if this can be related to Google Cloud in any way?

Comment: What is the origin URI? What is the URI of the request that results in a CORS error? Use the browser debugger to look up the exact URIs. You will not get a CORS error for same origin requests. You are overlooking something and making wrong assumptions.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) your complete php.ini content  (200  error's likely PHP is OOM) 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to minimize spiky.

Comment: A: https://justpaste.it/7xec4
B: https://justpaste.it/3nuyy
C: https://justpaste.it/91vzs
D: https://justpaste.it/34e5f
E: https://justpaste.it/9cl0h
F: Skipped in your comment.
G: https://justpaste.it/9gfa4
H: https://justpaste.it/8kwku (We are using Docker image php:8.1-fpm, so H contains php-fpm.conf)

Comment: Do you have a retry logic implemented in your service code?

Answer (score 1):

This error might be caused by expected internal behavior within the networking infrastructure of Cloud Run. Occasionally, maintenance does occur on this networking infrastructure, which can cause some connections to be closed.  Since Cloud Run's health checks are not network dependent, this can cause the container to be stuck and unable to communicate with the server.  Some Cloud Run applications are sensitive to this network connection drop as well.  As you were able to redeploy the Cloud Run container, you were able to "unstick" the container and it was able to run as intended.

**A recommended workaround and practice is to implement retry logic within your service code.**  This will allow the Cloud Run service to be able to reconnect to the servers when a network connection drops.

You have a website that makes requests to your Cloud Run service.
The Cloud Run service just stopped serving/responding to any requests.
This is also reflected in Cloud SQL because the Cloud Run service connects to Cloud SQL, so a decrease in requests to Cloud Run gets mirrored in Cloud SQL usage.

If that’s right, then the retry logic should be on the frontend. The purpose would be to retry requests from your website (frontend) to your Cloud Run service (backend).

Different frameworks provide different resources to implement retry logic. Here is a [Google Cloud documentation about the retry logic](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff#example_algorithm).

Comment: Wops sorry, didn't see your comment first. What retry logic are you talking about here? Application code? Or adding an extra layer somewhere in the Google Cloud Universe? Do you have any resources to point me to?