# Cloud Run suddenly starts timing out when processing any request

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We've been running a backend application on Cloud Run for about a year and a half now, and a month ago it suddenly stopped properly handling all requests at seemingly random times (about every couple of days), only working again once we redeploy from the latest image from Cloud Build. The application will actually receive the request, however it just doesn't do anything and eventually the request will just time out (504) after 59m59s (the max timeout), even a test endpoint that just returns 'Hello World' times out without sending a response.

The application is written in Python and uses Flask to handle requests. We have a Cloud SQL instance that is used as its database, however we're confident this is not the source of the issue as even requests that don't involve the DB in any form do not work and the Cloud SQL instance is accessible even when the application stops working. Cloud Run is deployed with the following configuration:

- CPU: 2
- Memory: 8Gi
- Timeout: 59m59s
- VPC connector
- VPC egress: private-ranges-only
- Concurrency: 100

The vast majority of endpoints should produce some form of log when they first start, so we're confident that the application isn't executing any of the code after being triggered. We're not seeing any useful error messages in Logs Explorer either, simply just 504 errors from the requests timing out. It's deployed with a 59m59s timeout, so it's not the case that the timeout has been entered incorrectly and even then, that wouldn't explain why it works again when it's redeployed.

We have a Cloud Scheduler schedule that triggers the application every 15 minutes, which sends to an endpoint in the application that checks if any tasks are due to run and creates Cloud Tasks tasks (which send HTTP requests to an endpoint on the same application) for any tasks that need performing at that point in time. Every time the application stops working, it does seem to be during one of these runs, however we're not certain it's the cause as the Cloud Scheduler schedule is the most frequent trigger anyway. There doesn't seem to be a specific time of day that the crashes take place either.

This is a (heavily redacted) screenshot of the logs. The Cloud Scheduler schedule hits the endpoint at 21:00 and creates a number of tasks but then hits the default 3m Cloud Scheduler timeout limit at 21:03. The tasks it created then hit the default 10m Cloud Tasks timeout limit at 21:10 without their endpoint having done anything. After that point, all requests to the service timeout without doing anything.

[image: Screenshot of logs]

[image]

The closest post I could find on SO was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73573956/php-service-in-google-cloud-run-suddenly-stops-responding-to-all-incoming-reques), their problem is also temporarily fixed by redeployment, however ours isn't sending 200 responses when it stops working and is instead just timing out without doing anything. We've tried adding retries to Cloud Scheduler + increasing its timeout limit, and we've also tried increasing the CPU and RAM allocation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: any solutions to this?

Comment: @darrenz not an ideal one, unfortunately. Our solution has been to have a Cloud Function that sends a test request to the application every minute and, if it fails, publish a message to a Pub/Sub topic that has a Cloud Build trigger subscribed to it, automatically redeploying it. Not ideal by any means, but means that downtime is rarely more than a minute.